# How to install UIBuilder on Pharo

Tags: installation, smalltalk, pharo, uibuilder

I'm learning Smalltalk for my graduation (Computer Science), and got started using [Pharo](http://www.pharo-project.org).

I've read and watched that there is a nice framework for UI building, called [UIBuilder tool](http://www.squeaksource.com/UIBuilder.html). But I'm confused on how to install it on Pharo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this unfortunately only works on old versions of Pharo.

The install instructions are what the registration section gives e/g/

In a transcript paste

```
MCHttpRepository
    location: 'http://www.squeaksource.com/UIBuilder'
    user: ''
    password: ''
```

Select that and choose DoIt from the menu.

This will then download the classes and install in the image. The tool that does this is Monticello for more on this see  the Pharo By Example [Monticello chapter](https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/27018/Monticello.pdf)

Comment: That doesn't do anything, it just defines a Monticello repository. You'd want the Gofer equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The old "UIBuilder" project seems to be dead/discontinued. The Squeaksource page
http://www.squeaksource.com/UIBuilder.html says:

"Failed attempt of develop a UI builder for Pharo-Smalltalk."

There is now a new "UI Painter" project developed as part of GSOC 2013
for Pharo based on Spec. More information can be found here : http://uipainter-gsoc.over-blog.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you can get away with it, build your UI with Glamour. That is included in Moose. Otherwise the supported (but very much in development) way to create UI's for Pharo is using Spec.

Comment: Spec and Glamour still doesn't include a User Interface Builder per se. There is significant effort from building a UI using a visual language and a textual language, so I wouldn't recommend it for UI building at least for newbies.